# A puzzling maximization issue using Abs[ ] in the constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the following pair of commands.

```
Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1, Abs[y] <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

> $\{2, \{x \rightarrow -1, y \rightarrow -1\}\}$

```
FindMaximum[{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1, Abs[y] <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

> $\{ 8.63643\times 10^{-21}, \{x \rightarrow -6.57131\times 10^{-11}, y \rightarrow -6.57131\times10^{-11}\}\}$

Now, I understand that `FindMaximum[]` is only looking for a *local maximum*, but what it finds is not that either. Any thoughts? Is it something about `Abs[]`?

**EDIT** Just to clarify in response to J.M.'s wise commentary, *just* using `&&` instead of a comma between the constraints makes no difference, though the full `PiecewiseExpand[]` does.

Comment: Something does seem off: `FindMaximum[{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1 // PiecewiseExpand[#, {x, y} ∈ Reals] &} // Evaluate, {x, y}]`

Comment: It seems to go wacko only when `1` is used.  It works fine with any other number (not that I've tried them all):  `FindMaximum[{x^2 + y^2, 
  Abs[x] <= 99999/100000 && Abs[y] <= 99999/100000}, {x, y}]` and `FindMaximum[{x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 2 && Abs[y] <= 2}, {x, y}]`.

Comment: I guess **Limitations of the Interior Point Method** section of [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html) is related. Also, notice if one uses `RealAbs` instead of `Abs`, or manually setting `Gradient -> "FiniteDifference"`, the warning `FindMaximum::eit` pops up.

Answer (score 4):

### Starting Point Issues

The problem here seems to be the choice of the *starting points* as can be seen from these "studies":

```
(* The original Problem" *)
pts["AbsNoStartPts"]  pts["AbsNoStartPts"] = Reap[
    FindMaximum[ 
        {x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1}, 
        {x, y}, 
        StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]
    ]
][[2, 1]];

(* using inequalities without starting points *)
pts["InequalityNoStartPts"] = Reap[
    FindMaximum[ 
        {x^2 + y^2, -1 <= x <= 1 && -1 <= y <= 1}, 
        {x, y}, 
        StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]
    ]
][[2, 1]];

(* the original problem using a starting point not too close to zero *)
pts["AbsStartPts"] = Reap[
    FindMaximum[ 
        {x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1}, 
        { { x, 0.1 } , { y, 0.1 } }, 
        StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]
    ]
][[2, 1]];
```

Now, we can see how the solver gets stuck once one starting value for either $x$ or $y$ is very close or equal to zero:

```
Map[
    ContourPlot[
        x^2 + y^2, 
        {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
        PlotLabel -> #, 
        Epilog -> { Red, Line[pts[#]], Point[pts[#]] }, 
        ImageSize -> Small] &,
    {"InequalityNoStartPts", "AbsNoStartPts","AbsStartPts"}
] // Row
```

[image: Initial Point Dependencies]

The issue is the lack of a clear gradient it seems if one component is too close to zero. Next to providing starting points for `FindMinimum` in more recent Versions of Mathematica (thank you, xzczd, for this information) we may simply increase the `WorkingPrecision`:

```
FindMaximum[
    {x^2 + y^2, Abs[x] <= 1 && Abs[y] <= 1}, 
    {x, y}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30
]//First // Round
```

> 2

Comment: Maybe somebody can give a good reason for the starting points being different when using `Abs` instead of the inequality? As always the *Mathematica Navigator* (still) is an invaluable source of information here. Using `NMaximize` may prove to be more robust than using `FindMinimum`?

Comment: Just a side note: The `WorkingPrecision -> 30` solution works in _v11.1_ but not in _v9_ and _v8_.

Comment: @xzczd Good to know, that there really are reasons to update versions. :)